# anchor tag href redirects to another without clicking the icon

Tags: jquery, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, datatable

I have made 2 tabs , in the second tab I have a datatable in which one column holds the anchor element...
In the anchor element I have "href" attribute in which I have called another function...
So, whenever I switch to second tab page automatically redirects to another page without the click of the icon...

Please find the code below:
This is the anchor element I am using...

```
<td><a href=${(this.open(JSON.parse(item.RelatedItems)[0].ItemId))}><i data-toggle="tooltip" title="Approve / Reject" class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

This is the function I have called in anchor tag:

```
protected open(rid){
var url : string;
let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
 web.lists.getByTitle("Test").items.select("UID,ID")
.filter("ID eq'" + rid"'").get()
.then((response)=>{
           url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +"/SitePages/Test.aspx?RID="+response[0].UID+"&tsk=apr&isEditable=0"
            window.location.replace(url);
        })
   }
```

Please suggest the workaround for the same.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are executing `window.location.replace` you just need to return the URL after creating it. The then callback should be.

```
.then((response)=>{
          var url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +"/SitePages/Test.aspx?RID="+response[0].UID+"&tsk=apr&isEditable=0"
            return url;
        })
   }
```

OR

As a alternative, you can create a button control and execute the function over `onClick()`

Comment: It is not working as well.... I have tried this now but it is giving me an error that "this.open" is not function  onclick =javascript:this.open(${a[0].ItemId})